# Problems with proving two sets are equal

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone help me with this? I tried solving it but I got stuck
[image]

Comment: If you get lost in the formal steps, perhaps a [Venn diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) will help to make the situation clear.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x$ is in the LHS. Then either $x\in A\cap B$ or $x\in B\cap C$ or $x\in C\cap A$.

$$x\in A\cap B \Rightarrow x \in A\cup B, C\cup A, B\cup C$$ So $x$ is in the RHS. You can do the same for the other two cases $x\in B\cap C$ or $x\in C\cap A$.

Now suppose that $x$ is an element of the RHS. Then $x$ is an element of each of the brackets on the RHS. Now $$x\in A\cup B \Rightarrow x\in A \text{ or } x\in B $$ Suppose $x\in A$. Then from the second bracket (of which we already know $x$ is an element) we get $$x\in B \text{ or } x\in C$$ From here we get $$(x \in A \text{ and } x \in B) \text{ or } (x \in A \text{ and } x \in C)$$ So either $$x\in A\cap B \text{ or } x \in C\cap A$$ which implies that $x$ is an element of the LHS.

I will leave the other cases for you.